# How to use .click() on element in front of another jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, layer

I'm working on a page that displays a map via jQuery, and I have a div layered in front of the map, with an x in the corner to be used to close it. When I disable the map, clicking the x closes the div (via jQuery's `fadeOut()` function), but when the map loads, the x does nothing.

Is there any way to enable the `.click()` function on a layered div like this? Using a delegated event handler does not solve the problem.

```
$('#close_btn').click(function() {
    $('#msg1').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click','#close_btn',function() {
    $('#msg1').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

```html
<div class="message" id="msg1">
    <div class="inner">
        <span class="title">Some stuff!</span>
        <span class="tip_msg">Some other stuff.</span>
        <span id="close_btn"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine as it is. Are you dynamically appending the HTML of the map to the page after it has loaded?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: In which case you need to use a delegated event handler. See the marked duplicate for more information

Comment: Like  `$(document).on('click','#close_btn',function(){ $('#msg1').fadeOut('fast');
 })`

Comment: That actually isn't solving the issue. Still works when the map is disabled, and ignored when the map loads.